# How to get Tweets which are more than a week old from Twitter?

Tags: twitter, tweets

For my research project, I need tweets containing a particular link(That is the search query). I have used Twitter APIs built with Python- both Twython and Tweepy (both REST and Streaming API). But none of them could give me tweets which are more than a week old. I understand, that is the general policy of Twitter. I have found applications which can  give me much older tweets, but they just display the tweets graphically. But in order to analyze the data, I need to download the data or store them in a file. There is another one which just gives me real time tweets, but no historic tweets. There are also a few others which just allows me to download my own tweets, which is again of no use to me. So, if there is any other way to do it, I need to find it. Help!